# Simple Jquery not working on Select2 element

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to color an element of a select2 element by getting the title of the chosen option and then searching for it on the page. The title and color are working and are correct but it seems that $(this) isn't working in the last line.
I also have the same code on a different page and everything is working as it should so I'm not quite sure why this is not.

Jquery

```
 $('.change-tags-select').on('change', function (e) {
          $('form.change-' + id).find('#select2-change-' + id + '-container > li').each(function(){
               var title = $(this).attr('title');
               var color = $('[value=' + title + ']').attr('data-id');
               $('#select2-change-' + id + '-container').find('[title="' + title + '"]').css('background-color', color);
       });
    });
```

HTML

```
<ul class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-usertags1-n6-container">
    <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Tag1" data-select2-id="select2-data-26-st3x"></li>
    <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Tag2" data-select2-id="select2-data-27-4pum"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you check the value of color?

Comment: Yes, it's saving the correct value.

Comment: Can you try to change background-color to background only?

Comment: Not working. I think the problem is that I have multiple select2 elements on the page and I'm targeting them by class. I can't target by ID because they are changed on page refresh.

Comment: This is something in don’t understand. Can you explain why you can’t add an id to the select elements? Also you can work with closest to get the first one and findnext for the second one and so on

Comment: I've updated the code. I added an ID and I'm now getting the correct element but for some reason .css() is not working.

Comment: I think you need to make an example. Your code isn't conveying the complete picture from what I can discern.

Comment: Okay, let me try to explain it as best as I can. 
I currently have a select2 element which generates span and an ordinary select element. All of the options have certain colors and I want to change the color of each element once it's selected. I added an ID to the HTML select element and the select2 element generated it's own ID (ex. select2-change-6-container; original id was change-6). The problem is that if I try to find the element with $("#change-" + id).on('change'...) where id=6, it doesn't work.

Comment: How will you find $("#change-" + id)... if you named it select2-change-6-container?